# SELECT DISTINCT count() in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a database where we can track bugs we have raised with our developers (Table: ApplixCalls) and track any correspondence related to the logged bugs (Table: Correspondence).

I'm trying to create a count where we can see the number of bugs which have no correspondence or only correspondence from us. This should give us the visibility to see where we should be chasing our developers for updates etc.

So far I have this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(ApplixCalls.OurRef) AS CountOfOurRef
    FROM ApplixCalls LEFT JOIN Correspondence ON ApplixCalls.OurRef = Correspondence.OurRef
    HAVING (((Correspondence.OurRef) Is Null) 
        AND ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed')) 
    OR ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed') 
        AND ((Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?])=True);
```

I'm finding that this part is counting every occasion we have sent an update, when I need it to count 1 where OurRef is unique and it only has updates from us:

```
  OR ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed') 
        AND ((Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?])=True);
```

Hopefully that makes sense...

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access does not support `count(distinct)`.  In your case, you can use a subquery.  In addition, your query should not work.  Perhaps this is what you intend:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT ApplixCalls.OurRef
      FROM ApplixCalls LEFT JOIN
           Correspondence
           ON ApplixCalls.OurRef = Correspondence.OurRef
      WHERE (((orrespondence.OurRef Is Null) AND (ApplixCalls.Position) <> 'Closed')) OR
              (ApplixCalls.Position <> 'Closed') AND (Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?] = True))
            )
      GROUP BY ApplixCalls.OurRef
    ) as x;
```

Modifications:

- You have a `HAVING` clause with no `GROUP BY`.  I think this should be a `WHERE` (although I am not 100% sure of the logic you intend).
- The `SELECT DISTINCT` is replaced by `SELECT . . . GROUP BY`.
- The `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is now `COUNT(*)` with a subquery.

EDIT:

Based on the description in your comments:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT ApplixCalls.OurRef
      FROM ApplixCalls LEFT JOIN
           Correspondence
           ON ApplixCalls.OurRef = Correspondence.OurRef
      WHERE (((orrespondence.OurRef Is Null) AND (ApplixCalls.Position) <> 'Closed')) OR
              (ApplixCalls.Position <> 'Closed') AND (Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?] = True))
            )
      GROUP BY ApplixCalls.OurRef
      HAVING SUM(IIF(Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?] = False, 1, 0)) = 0
    ) as x;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is very close to what I'm looking for. The last remaining part is that it needs to ignore occasions where Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?] = False, as this would indicate we have had a response from the devs, so we don't need to chase! Currently, if an ApplixCall correspondences has 2 true and 1 false, it is still being picked up in the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting all the element that respond to you condition you don't need DISTINCT .. distinct if for removing duplicate result

```
SELECT  Count(distinct ApplixCalls.OurRef) AS CountOfOurRef
FROM ApplixCalls LEFT JOIN Correspondence ON ApplixCalls.OurRef = Correspondence.OurRef
WHERE (((Correspondence.OurRef) Is Null) 
    AND ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed')) 
OR ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed') 
    AND ((Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?])=True);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem I'm having is that I am getting duplicates. The second part of my question key: 'I'm finding that this part is counting every occasion we have sent an update, when I need it to count 1 where OurRef is unique and it only has updates from us'. ApplixCalls.OurRef may have several correspondences related to it. For example, OurRef '9999' has 3 correspondences linked to it, of which all were sent from us (SBSUpdate? = true), I need this to count as 1. At the moment it would count as 3.

Comment: i have update the answer  .. seems you need count(distinct ... ) i also change the having with where

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand why are you using having clause. I hope this query will fullfill youe need.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Count(ApplixCalls.OurRef) AS CountOfOurRef
        FROM ApplixCalls LEFT JOIN Correspondence ON ApplixCalls.OurRef = Correspondence.OurRef
        HAVING (((Correspondence.OurRef) Is Null) 
            AND ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed')) 
        OR ((ApplixCalls.Position)<>'Closed') 
            AND ((Correspondence.[SBSUpdate?])=True);
```